# Value of variable disappears after few function calls

Tags: python

I'm making a parser with proxy support, couse of using free proxies, they often dies, so my code switch to other proxy, no problems here, but couse of switching i rerun function multiple times (2-7) and my parsed data disapears, I'm sure question is silly but can't find out it on my own, thx for reply!

Think, should cache var result somehow, couse var holds only link to object, and after few reruns link reapplies or problem in my function that reruns itself, please help to get it.

```py
def take():
    #  here I take ip:port, submit form, check if online, etc
    return proxy


def con(where):
    auto = take()
    #  proxy dict
    try:
        page = requests.get(where, headers={"content-type": "text"}, proxies=proxydict)
        return html.fromstring(page.content)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        con(where)


goods = []
goodsp = "some xpath here"
for n in range(1, 51):
    p = con("https://site&page=%s" % n)
    for el in (p.xpath(goodsp)):
        goods.append(el.get("href"))
```

So all works fine, but when proxy dies 2-7 times and then reconnects, I get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mi/PycharmProjects/testone/ya.py", line 67, in 
    for el in (p.xpath(goodsp)):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'xpath'

so my p var becomes None, what should I do to hold it with me?

Comment: in `con` add `return con(where)` inside `except`

Comment: @depperm oh my.... thx a lot man, you are my hero! 
How to mark your comment as solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on @depperm's comment, the problem is likely your recursive function not returning anything. For instance your execution flow may look like:

```
con(where) <- which DOESN'T return HTML to this one<-|
    -> error                                         | 
       -> con(where)                                 |<-to this call here-|
          -> error                                                        |
             -> con(where)                                                |
                 -> success -> returns HTML       ->        ->        ->  |
```

However, if you change the block

```
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        con(where)
```

To:

```
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        return con(where)
```

Then the resulting HTML will be fed back up the chain through all the recursive functions as you intended (or so we believe, but cannot confirm since it is not a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)