# Python: else statement returns True, though it's mentioned to return False

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a function that validates two lists passed as arguments and returns True if the structure of both the lists are same and returns False otherwise.

Tried with print statements at multiple places of the code and see no issue. Else statement prints "False" as expected, for different structure lists, but strangely function returns True, though it should return False.

```
def same_structure_as(original,other):
    if isinstance(original, list) and isinstance(other, list):
        if len(original) == len(other):
            for el in original:
                if isinstance(el, list):
                    orig_new = original[original.index(el)]
                    other_new = other[original.index(el)]
                    same_structure_as(orig_new,other_new)
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        print("False")
        return False

same_structure_as([1,[1,1]],[[2,2],2])
```

Since the structure of both the input lists are different, the code should return False. print statement correctly prints "False", but returns "True" even though i gave "return False"

Comment: @Prune It prints False, but returns True.  Done in a shell instead of a file, you see both values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to fix it is to simply `return` your recursive function (which I'm sure is what your intent was):

```
def same_structure_as(original, other):
    if isinstance(original, list) and isinstance(other, list):
        if len(original) == len(other):
            for el in original:
                if isinstance(el, list):
                    orig_new = original[original.index(el)]
                    other_new = other[original.index(el)]
                    return same_structure_as(orig_new, other_new) # just add a return here
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        print("False")
        return False

print(same_structure_as([1,[1,1]],[[2,2],2]))
```

Yields the correct:

> False
>
> False

I [drew a diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56138032/10924296) explaining this situation on a previous post

Comment: @SaranyaRaja Glad to hear! If this solved your problem it's standard to click the green check by the post to accept it as the solution (you can change this too if a better answer comes along) as this signals to posters the problem has been solved and closes the thread. When you get 15 rep you can upvote helpful questions/answers too. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 4):

You are not returning False if an inner list has a mismatch:

> ```
> def same_structure_as(original,other):
>     if isinstance(original, list) and isinstance(other, list):
>         if len(original) == len(other):
>             for el in original:
>                 if isinstance(el, list):
>                     orig_new = original[original.index(el)]
>                     other_new = other[original.index(el)]
>                     same_structure_as(orig_new,other_new) # here - the result is ignored
>             return True
>         else:
>             return False
>     else:
>         print("False")
>         return False
> ```

You need

```
def same_structure_as(original,other):
    if isinstance(original, list) and isinstance(other, list):
        if len(original) == len(other):
            for el in original:
                if isinstance(el, list):
                    orig_new = original[original.index(el)]
                    other_new = other[original.index(el)]
                    if not same_structure_as(orig_new,other_new): # early exit if not same 
                        return False
                     # else continue testing (no else needed - simply not return anything)
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        print("False")
        return False
```

elsewise you "detect/print" wrongness but never act upon.